# Are there any taxes on product purchsed from US and taken to India

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, india, electronic-items

Can i buy a MAC in US and take it to India? Ofcourse i can! But my question is do i have to pay extra taxes or something for that maybe in US or india?